# Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol' SwiftUI Text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am rewriting my app that randomises the numbers from the set for SwiftUI with Combine.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

private final class SomeViewState: ObservableObject {
        
        @Published var resultString = ""
        
    }
    
    struct SomeContent: View {
        
        @StateObject private var state = SomeViewState()
        
        func iterateAndRemove() -> (Set<Int>, Set<Int>){
            var numbers = Set<Int>(1...50)
            var results = Set<Int>()
            for _ in 1...3{
                let randomNumbers = numbers.randomElement()!
                results.insert(randomNumbers)
                numbers.remove(randomNumbers)
            }
        return (numbers, results)
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Some Text")
                    (...)
                
                Text($state.resultString)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(width: 195, height: 70)
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white).shadow(radius: 3))
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Randomise") {
                
                    let runFunction = iterateAndRemove()
                    theResult = runFunction.1
                    state.resultString = theResult.map(String.init).joined(separator: ", ")
                    
                }.padding()
```

As stated in the title I get the

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol' SwiftUI Text
```

error. The only solutions I found in the Internet were for when the button throws such an error.
Please help!

Comment: You can't use `@State` outside of a `View`, change it to `@Published` in your class (or delete the class and move the property to the view)

Comment: Thank you @Joakim Danielson. It was [@Published] before and it still threw the error. Putting it back as such :)
This doesn't solve the case though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Text` displays an immutable `String`, hence it's initialiser takes a `String`, not a `Binding<String>`.

So inject the `String`, not a `Binding` to it.

```
Text(state.resultString)
```

Moreover, `@State` should only be used on `View`s. `resultString` should be `@Published`, not `@State`.

Comment: Thanks @Dávid Pásztor it worked :)